# HTTPS request, unable to verify first certificate

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https, openssl

I'm trying to setup an local https server with express. To generate a key and certificate, I am using the `openssl` package and following [this tutorial](https://pki-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simple/index.html).

Here is my server file

```js
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const PORT = 1000;

app.post("/test", (req, res) => {
  console.log("received request");
  res.send("hello");
});

const keyPath = path.join(process.env.CERTS_DIR, "simple.org.key");
const certPath = path.join(process.env.CERTS_DIR, "simple.org.crt");

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(keyPath),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(certPath)
};

console.log({ options });
const server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(PORT);

server.on("error", function (err) {
  console.log("server.error: " + err);
});

server.on("listening", function () {
  console.log(
    `Secure server listening on port:${PORT}`
  );
});
```

I have no trouble starting my server. But when I make a request with the ssl option `rejectUnauthorized: true` I get the following error:

```
  "message": "request to https://localhost:1000/test failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate",
  "type": "system",
  "errno": "UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE",
  "code": "UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE"
}
```

For my certificate setup, I have:

- a root CA (self signed)
- a signing CA (signed by root CA)
- a server cert (signed by signing CA)

From what research I've done, it looks like my server cert is missing an intermediary CA.

In addition to this, I ran `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect localhost:1000 -servername localhost` and received the following output:

```
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=0 DC = org, DC = simple, O = Simple Inc, CN = www.simple.org
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 DC = org, DC = simple, O = Simple Inc, CN = www.simple.org
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
write W BLOCK
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing to make this work? I could have sworn the first time I set this up it worked but now it's giving me this error.

Comment: In short: append the intermediate CA cert to `cert`.

Comment: Just wanted to add since I can't post an answer, it turns out I was missing the `ca` property in my options for the https.createServer. When I pointed to my local ca, I received the code `0(ok)` from my `openssl s_client` command